# Mac mini fan replacement: amperage rating

Tags: hardware, mac-mini

I have a 2011 Mac mini server (quad-core i7, 2.0GHz) and the fan is going bad.

The current fan, part no. 610-0164 is rated 12V 0.66A.

The widely available replacement fans on eBay are rated 12V 0.5A.  They are marked as part no. 610-0069.

Does anyone have evidence that the replacement 0.5A fans are suitable for this computer, or should I try to find an exact replacement?

Comment: I replaced mine with the 610-0069 model and now my fan runs full blast as soon as I push the power button. Did you end up getting this one too and if so, did you have similar issues?

Comment: My email receipt does say it was the 610-0069 and I did not have similar issues; the replacement fan was a bit louder at idle but otherwise behaves the same as the original.  Make sure the computer's not actually overheating, and consider using some monitoring software to determine if the computer knows why the fan is running at full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Fan with 0.5Amp will do, since it will not overload the circuit, and only draw 0.5A while 0.66A is available.

It might not have enough power to provide sufficient air flow, thus it might run more, but that is only important if you run constantly at elevated Temperatures.

Check your mac mini model number to make sure it fits, since the one you are showing is for Mac Mini A1347 2010 2011 922-9953 610-0164 610-0069.